# Button Vs ImageButton, image stretching

Tags: android

I did a lot of search on whether to use Button or ImageButton. I need to use an image with selected states (pressed vs non-pressed). I was leaning towards using Button because I can easily put text under the image if I need to.

However  I noticed that with button, the background image stretches to match view bounds ( while this problem does not happen in ImageButton).

So I am confused now, what to use?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to have always the same size for your button no matter the size of the screen, you can use a `Button` with absolute width and height. If you want your image to have good proportions whatever the size of the button is, use `Image Button`.
Hope I helped

Comment: But then what about the text below the button if I use image button? Can I use drawables top

Comment: Simply add a TextView and make it clickable by putting a listenner on it

Comment: Then I have to both add them in RelativeLayout to make the alignment right into order for the text to be centered. This is getting complicated especially if I need to do it dynammically  and move them across screen based on touch events

Comment: Oh, yes, I didn't tried to dynamically move widgets but I think that if the Text area is defined by the position of the image, it will move as the image. I think ?